# email field is showing twice on profile update form

Tags: python, django, blogs, web-development-server

building a basic blog website using Django. In profile update page, i am getting email field twice. And one email field shows * mark for compulsory field and other one doesnt. I want both fields in update profile page to be compulsory(*), i.e username and email fields.

Codes are as follow:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from  .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mail = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

user.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
# from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm

# @csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to login!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm()
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm()
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form':p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

profile.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- FORM HERE -->
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
                {{ u_form|crispy }}
                {{ p_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Is it on purpose that the field in `UserUpdateForm` is called `mail` instead of  `email` ?

Comment: Thanks man! Correcting 'mail' to 'email' solved my problem. But I didn't understand fully. I've just started python and Django. Can you explain how and why the thing mentioned was happening.

Comment: Are you sure that both fields were called `email`? Or maybe one was called `mail` and one `email` ?